# How do I document the parameters of a function inside of a record type with Haddock?

Tags: haskell, haddock

I have a record type that contains a function. I'm trying to document the parameters to that function, but Haddock gives me a parse error. (When I actually compile the code to run it, it works fine.)

```hs
data Browserful jsval = Browserful
  {
    -- | See [EventTarget.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
    addEventListener    :: jsval  -- ^ The event target
                        -> String -- ^ The event to listen for, ie "click"
                        -> jsval  -- ^ The event target
                        -> IO ()  -- ^ Returns nothing
  }
```

And here's the error:

```sh
src\Web\Framework\Plzwrk\Browserful.hs:21:25: error:
    parse error on input `->'
   |
21 |                         -> String -- ^ The event to listen for, ie "click"
   |                         ^^
```

Does anyone know how to correctly document the function arguments here? Thanks!

Comment: I *think* `-- ^` is supposed to go after the `->`? That is, I think `ArgType ->` is seen as one unit, and you either put `-- |` before the `ArgType` or a `-- ^` after the `->`.

Comment: There is a long-standing feature request for this: https://github.com/haskell/haddock/issues/82